duende identity server: authenticate using google and call remote api
I'm testing Identity server.
I want users to authenticate using Google on our front and then access backend apis.
I successfully logged in using Google and added scopes to the access token:

I added a "tenantID"
I added a "LicenseID"
I added user roles.

The problem happens when calling the backend. The access token does not contain any of the scopes. It "only" contains the sub.
Dump of the token once Google authentication succeeds:

Dump of the token in the backend:

as you can see, email, name, roles, tenantID, etc... are "lost".
It looks like the access token is the token of the client that requested the Google user token, but I  needed the access token of the authenticated user.
For my tests, I used various sample in Samples-main\IdentityServer\v7\BFF
Key point is that I'm using bff library to map remote api and add automatically the access token:
app.MapRemoteBffApiEndpoint("/remote/user-token", "https://localhost:6001")
.RequireAccessToken(Duende.Bff.TokenType.User);
BFF Code


using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Duende.Bff.Yarp;
using Duende.IdentityServer;
using IdentityServer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("IdentityModel", LogEventLevel.Debug)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Duende.Bff", LogEventLevel.Debug)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
            .CreateLogger();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSerilog();

//JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
//builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services
    .AddBff()
    .AddRemoteApis()
    .AddServerSideSessions();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
    {
        // set session lifetime
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);

        // sliding or absolute
        options.SlidingExpiration = false;

        // host prefixed cookie name
        options.Cookie.Name = "__Host-bff-token-exchange";

        // strict SameSite handling
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001"; // builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:IdentityServerAuthority"];
        options.ClientId = "bff";
        options.ClientSecret = "edited";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.Scope.Add("api");      
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.Scope.Add("cloudiwayapp");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName);
                options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.MapInboundClaims = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");
        options.DisableTelemetry = true;
    });

builder.Services.AddUserAccessTokenHttpClient("api",
    configureClient: client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:6001/api");
    });
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseBff();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers()
        .RequireAuthorization()
        .AsBffApiEndpoint();
app.MapBffManagementEndpoints();

app.MapRemoteBffApiEndpoint("/remote/user-token", "https://localhost:6001")
    .RequireAccessToken(Duende.Bff.TokenType.User);

app.Run();



What is important for us is to know the roles of the user (ie administrator,viewer, etc... and the tenantId so that we can know who is the customer who is calling our backend api). Indeed, several users of the same company can collaborate on a project. They share a same TenantId (customerId) and have different permissions on the project.
